# The wget github action has been deleted. How can I find a repo hosting a fork of this action?

Tags: github, wget

The github repo [wei/wget](https://github.com/wei/wget) and associated github account [wei](https://github.com/wei) have been deleted. Is there a way to find a mirror of this in a fork somewhere?

Looking around for wget github actions gives links to this repo, which suggests this happened very recently.